# Getting index/value of item which matched using $match -> $in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

Update (as per comments):

**Collection 'documents' looks like this:**

```
[{
    _id:ObjectId(someobjectid),
    object_data:{
        people:[
            {id:"b@outlook.com",last_login:"2016-02-10T05:30Z00"},{id:"x@gmail.com",last_login:"2016-02-10T01:30Z00"}
        ],
        comment_body:"Hello this is a comment body and has a lot of text!",
        comment_type:"response",
        id_deleted: false,
        title:"Some title"
    },
    other_info:"Some other string info",
    display_image:"<base64string>",
    code:"some_code"
},{
    _id:ObjectId(someobjectid),
    object_data:{
        people:[
            {id:"a@gmail.com",last_login:"2016-02-10T05:30Z00"}}
        ],
        comment_body:"Some other comment!",
        comment_type:"debate",
        id_deleted: false,
        title:"Some other title"
    },
    other_info:"Some other string info",
    code:"some_code_not_unique"
}]
```

Now, I will be getting a list of email addresses as a part of user input. These emails are a part of a collection in a different database and different collection `history` which has some other set of information and looks like this:

**Collection 'history' structure:**

```
[{
    _id:ObjectId(bsonobjectid),
    code:'98754654689879',
    email:'b@outlook.com',
    history:[]
}]
```

I am trying to check if any document exists in the `documents` collection where one of the email addresses from user input matches  with the `object_data.people` and add the same document (projected version of it) to my `history` collection's `history` set.

To get the documents that match user input emails list I'm doing an `aggregate()` in Pymongo:

```
emails= ['a@gmail.com','b@outlook.com','c@yahoo.com'] #this list is dynamic and may or may not have a matched documents collection

pipe  = [
        {
            '$match':{
                'object_data.people.id': {'$in':emails}
                }
        },
        {
            '$project':{
                'email':<need the index/value of the matched item in the emails list>,
                'object_data':'$object_data',
                'code':'$code',
                'title':'$object_data.title'
            }
        }
    ]

res = db.documents.aggregate(pipe)
```

Now this returns me a list of matched documents as expected.

The problem is now based on the matched item in the `emails` list I have to do a bulk update in another collection.

Is there a way to get the **value of the item**(or index) which matched at aggregation?

My bulk update would look like this:

```
bulk_query = db.history.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

for doc in res:
    bulk_query.find({
        'code':'some_code',
        'email':doc['email'] #value of the matched element (or the index of the item matched will do as I can reconstruct here)
    }).update({
         '$addToSet':{
             'history':doc
         }
    })

result = leads_bulk_query.execute()
```

Note:

1. I'm trying to avoid looping through the `emails` list and matching
   it with the response of aggregation in python, the result of
   aggregation could be substantially large.
2. I know I can `$unwind` during aggregate and get documents per `object_data.people.id` and get desired result, but again, I'm
   looking for a solution that is less costly in terms of performance.

Thanks in advance. Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry but what do you need the index for? This is really unclear as to what you mean. Is this supposed to the the index of the email in your "provided" list that matced the document? Or is it the index of an array field in the matched document where something in the list matched? In etiher case I also do not clearly see how this relates to a position needed to update another document.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of the matched item in the emails list. That will get me to update my other collection.

Comment: You should show a full example of what you want to do, including the document you want to update and expected results on query query and update. It's **possible** in the latest release of MongoDB but you **should not** really use that method. If you are just after the matched index then simply compare back against the source array as you iterate the result list. This is a real case of *"just because you can does not mean that you should"*